# declaring object of a class having all virtual functions

Tags: c++, oop, virtual-functions

Actually, it's my final term exam question.
Which of the following will create a compile time error?

1. Declaring object of a concrete class in the definition of main function.
2. Writing output statement, in constructor statement.
3. Declaring object of a class having at least one virtual function.
4. Declaring objects of a class having all virtual functions.

I've chosen 4th one. But still confused. Need help!

Comment: Umm...none of those cause a compiler error.

Comment: Final exam question .. the answer should represent your knowledge of the subject ... not your ability to get someone else to provide the answer.

Comment: What's a constructor statement?

Comment: Are you sure they wrote "concrete" instead of "abstract"?

Comment: 4 is correct if you meant "pure virtual functions" rather than "all virtual functions".

Comment: You can declare classes in a function? Haha, I actually learned something! Really though, that was the only one of which I thought it would cause a compiler error, and then I figured out it didn't. I think you copied the question wrongly.

Comment: @AartStuurman, While you can, the statement was the declaration of an instance of a class, not the class itself.

Comment: I didn't copied wrong... It is the as same as it was asked. I've the snapshot too.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII I just asked the answer here for my own sake... this question has already been asked and they are not gonna ask the same question twice a day

Comment: @Jack molbdnilo might be right. I have never seen someone call 'pure virtual' functions an 'all virtual' function though.

Comment: hmm... alright, then may be they spelled it wrong. I'm still checking it again and again, it is the same

Comment: "All virtual functions" being used to mean "one or more pure virtual functions" is not worthy of an exam question and should not be counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some questions might be interpretable differently, so I will sum those up here. Note however, that some of these interpretations are not actually synonymes, but just my thoughts on what your teacher could have meant to say.

**1. Declaring object of a concrete class in the definition of main function.**

See this question: [What is the difference between a concrete class and an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149207/what-is-the-difference-between-a-concrete-class-and-an-abstract-class).
This shows it is valid to instantiate or declare a concrete class. The main function is no special exception to this.

Conclusion: `this is valid.`

**2. Writing output statement, in constructor statement.**

By `constructor statement`, I assume the `constructor function` of a class or struct, or something alike, is meant. Usually, I would say that an `output statement` is something like writing to the console. However, as the questions use kind of weird language anyway, one could say that by `output` statement the `return` statement is meant.

Output, as in writing to the console for example, is perfectly legal in a constructor function.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "I made a Foo\n";
    }
}
```

Output, as in returning something from a function, is not legal in a constructor.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        return 3; // not legal
    }
}
```

Conclusion: `If this is valid or not depends on how you interpret the question.`

**3. Declaring object of a class having at least one virtual function.**

`Virtual functions` in classes are explained here: [C++ Virtual/Pure Virtual Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306778/c-virtual-pure-virtual-explained).
The question is clear in that the one or more virtual function are `not pure virtual`, so:

Conclusion: `this is valid.`

**4. Declaring objects of a class having all virtual functions.**

See my explanation of answer 3 for an explanation of `virtual` and `pure virtual` functions.
The straightforward interpretation of this answer is: Is it legal to declare an object of a class of which all functions are virtual? In this case the statement is valid, see answer 3.

However, you could interpret `all virtual functions` as `pure virtual functions`, in which case instantiating the class is not valid.

Conclusion: `If this is valid or not depends on how you interpret the question.`

**Final conclusion**

Answer 1 and 3 both describe valid C++. However, answer 2 and 4 can be interpreted in multiple ways, so the answer is not clear.

**Personal thought**

I have never ever heard of someone calling a `return statement` an `output statement`. Neither have I heard of someone calling a `pure virtual function` an `all virtual function`. I think your teacher is weird.

Answer (score 1):

None of the four options

1. Declaring object of a concrete class in the definition of main function.
2. Writing output statement, in constructor statement.
3. Declaring object of a class having at least one virtual function.
4. Declaring objects of a class having all virtual functions

would necessarily give a compilation error.

Any of them would give a compilation error if you include a syntax error, say.

However, it's unclear what the author means by "constructor statement", that's not a standard term.

---

It's *possible* that by "all virtual functions" the author means "one or more pure virtual functions". If so then then that's probably the intended answer.